# Why does a list comprehension over a zip() call return a list containing the zip object instead of a list of zip()'s return values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Playing around with python3 REPL and noticed the following:

Why are `print( [zip([1,2,3], [3,1,4])] )` and `print( list(zip([1,2,3], [3,1,4])) )` different?

The first returns `[<zip object at 0xblah>]` and the second returns `[(1,3), (2,1), (3,4)]`.

Trying to understand why the list comprehension in the first statement doesn’t give me the result that the `list()` constructor gives - I think I'm confused about the difference between list comprehension and `list()` and would appreciate insight into what's happening under the hood.

Searching gives me [this question on lists and tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282745/in-python-whats-the-difference-between-a-list-comprehension-with-a-list-and-a-t/19282997) which doesn't answer my question.

Edit: A suggested question on [The zip() function in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683959/the-zip-function-in-python-3) is very helpful background, but does not address the confusion in my question about the difference between a *list comprehension* and a *list literal,* so i prefer the submitted answer below as more complete.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The zip() function in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683959/the-zip-function-in-python-3)

Comment: `[zip([1,2,3], [3,1,4])]` *is not a list comprehension*. That is a list literal with a single element, the value you get by evaluating the expression `zip([1,2,3], [3,1,4])` which of course is a `zip` object

Comment: `[x]` simply means "a list containing x", whereas `list(x)` means "a list containing the elements of x". They are not interchangeable (and neither of them is a list comprehension).

Comment: The equivalent of ``list(x)`` is ``[*x]``, not ``[x]``. Try ``[*zip([1,2,3], [3,1,4])]``.

Comment: thanks @MisterMiyagi - is `[*x]` considered a "list comprehension"? trying to understand what the `*` does - is it shorthand for a list comprehension or does it call the list constructor `list()`?

Comment: `[*x]` is not a list comprehension. It's a list containing `*x`, which means "unpack the items of `x`". `[*x]` will give you the same outcome as `list(x)`. A list comprehension always incorporates the words `for` and `in`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first statement is *not* a list comprehension, a list comprehension would give you the same result. It is just a list literal containing a zip object:

This would be a list comprehension:

```
[value for value in zip([1,2,3], [3,1,4])]
```

The above will print the same as `list(zip([1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 4]))`.

---

In general, `[something]` means: A list with one element: `something`.

On the other hand, `list(something)` means: Iterate over the values in something, and make a list from the result. You can see the difference for example by putting primitive objects inside it, like a number:

```
>>> [2]
[2]
>>> list(2)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```